# What would happen if I inject the charges (ESD) at PCB many times and PCB is completely floated (isolated) from the earth?

Tags: capacitor, esd, electrostatic

Just I wonder:
If I inject the charges (ESD) at PCB many times and PCB is completely floated (isolated) from the earth.
Will charges be dissipated or remain?

I think charges will be charged in the conductors like capacitor.
If I touch it, charge will flow out.

Is that right?

Comment: Ahn JIn Ho - Hi, Your now-deleted "thank you answer" suggests that you have received as much help as you need. In order to mark the topic as solved, please consider ["accepting" the answer which most helped you](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). Although accepting an answer isn't mandatory, it is *encouraged* as your question is then shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, it makes it clear that you aren't waiting for more answers, and we don't get nagged for it being a question without an accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the %RH and the surface dust, flux or other contaminants.   Even floating PCB’s have some leakage currents with TBD Gohm * picofarad = T, time constants.  So dwell time between discharges is often specified with an environmental in ESD susceptibility tests.   Accumulation of charge voltages will occur but never last forever.

Answer (score 2):

> If I inject the charges (ESD) at PCB many times and PCB is ***completely floated (isolated)*** from the earth.

The charges will remain. You've specified that the PCB is completely isolated, so there is nowhere for them to flow to.

If you touch it, you provide a conducting path, and the charges flow out through you.

Answer (score 1):

This would be like charging up a capacitor where the PCB was one plate and a plate at distance infinite (probably the Earth) was the second plate.